# Unable to get Acess token from authorization code using Uber api

Tags: swift, uber-api

I am getting this error = "unsupported_grant_type" in step 3 of the authorization, however I am successfully able to login via facebook while trying to login using uber api. I am developing an app in swift where I need to book taxi using uber api for which access token is needed.

```
    let postBody = [
        "client_secret": "\(uber_client_secret)",
        "client_id": "\(uber_client_id)",
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "redirect_uri": "\(uber_redirect_uri)",
        "code": "\(code)",
        "scope": "profile"

    ]
```

let urlString = "https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token"
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue. Does that happen often/always for you? The error indicates that your `grant_type` value is not sent as `authorization_code`... Did you try the same with cURL?  ```curl -F 'client_secret=<CLIENT_SECRET>' \
    -F 'client_id=<CLIENT_ID>' \
    -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    -F 'redirect_uri=<REDIRECT_URI>' \
    -F 'code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE_FROM_STEP_2' \
    https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token```

Comment: yes, it happens always however i can login using facebook and get the access token.This is what i am doing           
        let urlString = "https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token"        
        Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: postBody, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:nil)
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response.result.value! as Any)   // result of response serialization
        }

Comment: Can you share the exact request and response?

Comment: {"scope":"history_lite history profile ride_widgets all_trips request_receipt request","client_secret":"","redirect_uri":"http://localhost/","client_id":"","code":"some data","grant_type":"authorization_code"}REQUEST https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token    I am Also facing same issue did you find solution for this

Comment: I have the exact same issue.... Anyone got a Solution ?